# Position items below each other in one anchor item

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do you position items below each other in a single`<a></a>` using angular material toolbar?

I want the icon above the user name and both items need to be centered in the middle and not next to each other as in the stackblitz below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djay7v

Answer (score 0):

You are almost where near to answer

Try  below code in `sidenav-autosize-example.html`

```
<mat-icon mat-list-icon style="font-size: 150px; height: 150px;color: rgba(244, 92, 27, 0.356);margin: 0 auto;">account_circle</mat-icon> 
   <span style="position:relative;top:75px;right:20px">Current Username</span>
   <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
   <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djay7v-ikd8mz)

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your fast reaction. Is there a way, that this can be flexible? Because if I try to render a short name or a longer name,  it is not centered anymore?